# graph-tool: How to change vertex colors?

Tags: python, graph-tool

How can I set the background color of a vertex?

I know there should be a property dictionary or something but I can't find an example.

I need it to color different kind of vertices in a bipartite graph:

```
gtdraw.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, 
                  vertex_fill_color=part, 
                  vertex_font_size=6, 
                  output_size=(5000, 5000), 
                  output="img/pic.png")
```

Comment: By 'background color of a vertex', do you mean a halo effect or the color of the vertex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By background color of the vertex, i'm assuming you mean vertex_fill_color property.

The following code is taken from [here](http://ryancompton.net/2014/10/05/graph-tools-visualization-is-pretty-good/)

```
# Normalised RGB color.
# 0->Red, 1->Blue
red_blue_map = {0:(1,0,0,1),1:(0,0,1,1)}
# Create new vertex property
plot_color = g.new_vertex_property('vector<double>')
# add that property to graph
g.vertex_properties['plot_color'] = plot_color
# assign a value to that property for each node of that graph
for v in g.vertices():
    plot_color[v] = red_blue_map[g.vertex_properties['value'][v]]

gt.graph_draw(g,
              vertex_fill_color=g.vertex_properties['plot_color'])
```

The code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

A complete list of vertex properties can be found [here](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.graph_draw). I am unsure of what you mean by 'background color'. If you want to add a halo effect on the vertices, you can set `vertex_halo` to `True` and use `vertex_halo_color` and `vertex_halo_size` to control the effect. If you just want to change the color of the vertex or the outline, you can use `vertex_color` and `vertex_fill_color` like you already are.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background color with the keyword argument `vertex_fill_color`, as you do it. Just check that `part` stores the vertex properties associated with the bipartite information (i.e. which part).

For a simple example you can take a look at the end of [An Example: Building a Price Network](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#an-example-building-a-price-network) which show how to draw a network where the vertex colors represent the age of the vertex, from older (red) to newer (black). Here is the illustration taken from this [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) example:

[image]

I hope this will help you.